# Shift logo after hiding navigation symbols in beamer

Tags: beamer, graphics, positioning

I have a `beamer` presentation using the `Warsaw` theme in which I have a logo and I'm hiding the navigation symbols. The navigation symbols are hidden, but the logo remains in the same place. I can fix this by mocking about with some negative space, but I was wondering if there is a *better* solution? E.g., a solution that would work if at some point the height of the hidden navigation symbols is changed.

This is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Warsaw}

\logo{\includegraphics[scale=.25]{logo}}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

With the navigation symbols this results into this:
[image: Result with the navigation symbols]

and without the navigation symbols this gives:
[image: Result without the navigation symbols]

This is the solution I got using negative space:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Warsaw}

\logo{\includegraphics[scale=.25]{logo}\vspace{-8pt}}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

which results in

[image: Solution with shifted logo]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use calculate the height of one of the navigation symbols and drop the logo down by the required amount:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Warsaw}
\newlength{\navigationsymbolheight}
\settoheight{\navigationsymbolheight}{\NoHyper\insertframenavigationsymbol}
\logo{\raisebox{-\navigationsymbolheight}{\includegraphics[scale=.25]{example-image}}}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I like this solution best, since I occasionally disable the logo for some slides. That seems to be a bit more difficult with the other solution.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to add the logo image just before the `footline` template is built, using something like

```
\addtobeamertemplate{footline}{\hfill\includegraphics[scale=.25]{example-image}\hspace*{0.5em}\par\vspace{2pt}}{}
```

Change the lengths used in the `\hspace` and `\vspace` commands to the desired values. A compete example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\addtobeamertemplate{footline}{\hfill\includegraphics[scale=.25]{example-image}\hspace*{0.5em}\par\vspace{2pt}}{}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]